# Forcing, $ p \Vdash q \in \dot{G} \Rightarrow p \leq q $

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I was wondering if a poset is separative if

$ p \Vdash q \in \dot{G} ~~ \Rightarrow p \leq q$

I think it's clear that $ p, q \in G $ and hence are compatible but I am not seeing why ( if it's true ) $ p \leq q$. I don't know if perhaps we can use separativity( i.e. that $ p \not\leq q \Rightarrow \exists r \leq p $ such that $ r \bot q$ ). That said I wanted to use this to find a dense subset that is perhaps predense below $ q$ and that must contain $p$ so that we can reach a contradiction using separativity and the definition of Genericity. I don't see how yet though.

Thanks for any thoughts/help!

Comment: With $r$ as above, what does $r$ force about $q$?

Comment: Thanks, I believe $ r \Vdash p \in \dot{G}$ and $r  \Vdash q  \not\in \dot{G}$. I don't see a contradiction to $  p \not\leq q$ but i'll think about it.

Comment: Ah, okay. So since $ r \leq p$ and $ r \Vdash q \not\in \dot{G}$, we have a contradiction since $ r \leq p$ should tell us that $r$ forces whatever $p$ forces , i.e. $ r \Vdash q \in \dot{G}$. Which is a contradiction. Thanks Andres.